# Reverse using char arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

i want to use the following program to reverse the words using an array, as in the first character to be replaced by the last one in a word:

```
    void reverseit(char arr[])
    {
    int len= strlen(arr);   

    for(int i=0; i<=len/2; i++) 
        {
                char temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[len-i];
                arr[len-i]=arr[i];
        }
}
    int main()
    {
    char arr[100]={};
    cout<<"enter words:  ";
    cin.get(arr,100);
    reverseit(arr);
    cout<<arr;
    }
```

There seems to be no error, but when i output the array in the main no output is generated, any leads?

Comment: Please, read the inner loop again and wonder where the `temp` should have been used. Though you really should be wondering why you didn't use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: Also, the operation does not even make sense! You see, these days a "character" may span more than one `char`.

Comment: You are swapping the first byte with the trailing null byte. No wonder your reversed string is empty.

Comment: Also note that there's [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: @DanielJour +1 for suggesting not reinvent the wheel!!

Comment: I'm not sure if you interpret the exercise correctly; your code is reversing the characters of a sentence, which is something different than reversing words, isn't it?

Comment: please guys you need to understand the question if asked in a specific manner it surely has to do something with the concept applied. I've been noticing lately that people start criticizing the method applied, as in this case. I already know the swap function and reverse, but I need to do this type of work for something specific. Shouldn't really bother if one has not a valid attempt to solve the solution. @JanHudec

Comment: @StephanLechner yes you got it right

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@Werner Henze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023911/werner-henze), the **reverseit** function actually reversing the null byte to the first byte.

Excluding the string-terminating null byte from the reverse algorithm should do the trick.

```
void reverseit(char arr[])
{
    int len= strlen(arr) - 1;

    for(int i=0; i<=len/2; i++)
    {
        char temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[len-i];
        arr[len-i]=temp;
    }
}
```